# WEP Security for Internet Sharing?

Tags: macos, internet-sharing

I have a Nintendo DS to connect to the internet, but my router does not support WEP. I used to be able to create a WEP internet share on my MacBook 2010, but after the upgrade to 10.11.4, I cannot.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Apologies if this sounds like a dumb question, but why use WEP instead of the more secure WPA-AES?

Comment: Because, Darkstar, the DS only supports WEP encryption. Not WPA. So I want to create a WEP network on my Mac, because my router can't change to WEP.

Answer (score 1):

WEP was completely removed in Yosemite:

http://tidbits.com/article/15158

WEP is broken enough that you might just consider using an open Wifi connection (Security: None) but if you want to have a basic level of protection to stop someone from just walking into the equivalent of an open door the best solution would be to get a cheap secondary wifi router and set it up with it's own SSID with WEP, making sure to turn off DHCP on the router and connect it via a LAN rather than the WAN port (Apple Airports can just be put into Bridge Mode). If you're worried about security you could unplug the secondary router when you're not using it or disable it's Wifi.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the time and technical chops, one option may be to set up a virtual machine on your Mac that is running Linux. For cost reasons, you could use the free VirtualBox. Then set up the Linux distro to share with a WEP key.  Then you merely need to activate the virtual machine when you want to get your DS online.

Here is a post describing the tool on Linux that you might use to set this up: [Host APD: the Linux way to create a Wi-Fi access point](https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/)

There's no guarantee that the virtual box network card is supported, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Hi Darkstar, I have Ubuntu installed in Fusion, but I'm not sure how to go about giving it direct access to my computer's Wi-Fi controller—the only options seem to be for giving it access to the network rather than the interface itself. Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, It doesn't really need direct access to the network card. All you need is to have it share the connection to the network over WEP encryption, right?

Comment: In order to share the connection, I believe it needs direct access to the network interface, so it can broadcast as a base station rather than an endpoint. This area is not my forte though, so I could be completely wrong about this. Do you have first-hand experience doing what you suggested in your answer?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to an article from a guy looking to do the something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm pretty sure it's not possible, at least with Fusion. The person who wrote the article you found is running Linux natively, and it seems that Fusion simulates an Ethernet connection using whatever connection you choose rather than allowing the OS to connect directly.

Comment: Sorry. Wish I could have found a better answer for you.  Best of luck!